# How to deploy web service into Amazon EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I have configured a cluster in EKS but I am not able to deploy a web service into EKS. I tried the steps mentioned in  https://github.com/spjenk/HelloSpringEKS but I failed to create tiller-deploy.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl get pod --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                              READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   tiller-deploy-5d6cc99fc-hn6dm     0/1     ContainerCreating   0          6h45m
```

The tiller-deploy just stuck in **ContainerCreating** status.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Describe the pod and see the reason for the "ContainerCreating" state.

Comment: describe `tiller-deploy-5d6cc99fc-hn6dm` and share the event logs. `kubectl describe pod tiller-deploy-5d6cc99fc-hn6dm -n kube-system`